# Is the width of the Bootstrap Dropdownlist changable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I create asp.net MVC web project using Visual Studio 2015, the Bootstrap is used when I create UI form of razor view. I want to increase the width of Bootstrap Dropdownlist  by using the following codes, but the code doesn't work, is width of the bootstrap dropdownlist changeable?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            <label for ="coordDesc">Coord </label>  
        </div>   
        <div class="col-xs-9" id="t1">                                
                    @Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new SelectList(ViewBag.MovieType, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:1200px;" })           
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the container is 1200 px (minus the margin used by form-controls)? Use the F12 tools to verify.

Comment: yes, I make sure, actually, you can verify it by creating a simple test case using my code, please let me know if you have different result. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the width of dropdown list by adjusting the bootstrap grid. The width of dropdown will automatically adjust based on its parent's `width` because of `form-control` class. Hope this will help!

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
        <label for ="coordDesc">Coord </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>-</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81455/

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 mvc template to develop my mvc web app, all views are based on this template, your codes do not work in this template. after further testing,  I found that  if I commented out the .css file below in _Layout.cshtml file, then it works well, <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@  //I commented out this line of code.
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

Comment: but this @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") file is provided by the mvc template, if I removed it, the entire UI will be impacted, is there any way to keep it and also make the width of the dropdownlist changeable?

Comment: You can use `max-width` property.

Comment: Try this: 

`@Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new SelectList(ViewBag.MovieType, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width: 100%" })`

Comment: the max-width just adjusted the width to the max length of content, I think this works fine as long as it shows the max length of the content,

Comment: After doing more investigation, I find out the razor view provided by Visual Studio 2015 uses their own css style impacted the result. in F12 key, I found this dropDownlist is converted to <select> <option> and in the css style, it has input, select, textarea {

max-width:280px; //here is the trick, if I changed the width here, then the width dropdownlist is changed. 

} so in this case, since I can not change the default .css provided by the mvc template, so I have to find a way to overwrite this line of css code, any idea?

Comment: Just add `@id = "name-of-your-id"` then add this to your css file `#name-of-your-id{ max-width: 100% }`



e.g. `@Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new SelectList(ViewBag.MovieType, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "name-of-your-id" })`

Answer (score 0):

what works for me:
@Html.DropDownList("MovieType", new SelectList(ViewBag.MovieType, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width: 100%" })
and I took this answer from [L Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9709482/l-cruz) 's comment